# Is there any way to convert a ViewGroup into a button for accessibility?

Tags: android, kotlin, button, accessibility, viewgroup

I have a custom view with four Textview inside a constraint layout.
The problem is that i´m implementing accessibility, and this view must be a child of some kind of button, to inherit the behavior of "..., Button" sayd by Talkback.
Is there a way to convert a view to type Button? Or any way to make the talkback recognize this view as a Button?

My xml is like this:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
  <CustomViewGroup>
    <AppCompatTextView>
  </CustomViewGroup>
  <CustomViewGroup>
    <AppCompatTextView>
  </CustomViewGroup>
  <CustomViewGroup>
    <AppCompatTextView>
  </CustomViewGroup>
  <CustomViewGroup>
    <AppCompatTextView>
  </CustomViewGroup>
  <View>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your customview should extend "Button" class.
Or you can use contentDescription.
On each text view, add a content description with the text you wish (like: "action one button")

Comment: The first option is good. The second one is not. Is not good to force the type of view just in the ContentDescription. There should be a code to say a custom view that it is a Button, and the talkback recognize it as a Button...